# how to set up or down to rectangles in jointJs

Tags: jointjs

```
let r1 = new joint.shapes.standard.Rectangle({
  position: { x: 200, y: 300 },
  size: { width: 400, height: 200 },
  attrs: {
    body: { fill: '#d2d2d2', rx: 6, ry: 2, stroke: 'green', strokeWidth: 3 },
    label: { text: item.name, refY: 10, fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold', fontVariant: 'small-caps' }
  }
});
r1.set('z', 999);
let r2 = new joint.shapes.standard.Rectangle({
  position: { x: 400, y: 300 },
  size: { width: 300, height: 200 },
  attrs: {
    body: { fill: '#d2d2d2', rx: 6, ry: 2, stroke: 'green', strokeWidth: 3 },
    label: { text: item.name, refY: 10, fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold', fontVariant: 'small-caps' }
  }
});
this.graph.addCells([r1, r2]);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MbmR.png)

## Description

i have created two rectangle in jointjs named as 1 and 2 in attached image 
  the problem is that when i try to move 1 from 2 then content of 1 goes down to 2
  how can i move rect 1 above to 2

Answer (score 1):

When we set value of z index for rectangle 1 as
r1.set('z', 999);
on the other hand we also have to set the value of z index for r2 
which should be less than r2 if we want to see r1 above to r2
when i set z for r2 as 
r2.set('z', 100);

solved my problem